# anyway to remove not needed css in laravel using blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have 4 blade page

```
=> layout.blade.php
=> index.blade.php
=> contact.blade.php
```

In ***layout.blade.php*** i have two yield

One Is:

`@yield('css') // to add additional css`

Another One Is:

`@yield('script') //to add additional script`

***index.blade.php*** extends ***layout.blade.php***

so that i can add `section('css')` and `section('script')` for additional css or script only for ***index.blade.php*** page

Now the problem is: In ***layout.balde.php*** has all the common link and script But i don't want those link to every page. i want some way to; not to load a specific link or some link in some page that extends ***layout.blade.php***.

Example:

```
=> layout.blade.php
    -> <link href="one.css">
    -> <link href="two.css">
=> index.blade.php extends layout.blade.php
    -> <link href="one.css"> // because index extends layout
    -> <link href="two.css"> // because index extends layout
=> contact.blade.php extends layout.blade.php
    -> <link href="one.css"> // because index extends layout (i don't want to load this link)
    -> <link href="two.css"> // because index extends layout
```

**Note**

I NEED SOME DYNAMIC WAY TO SAY FROM ***contact.blade.php*** TO OFF THIS LINK OR SOME LINK THAT COME FROM ***layout.blade.php***

Comment: You probably want to use some sort of asset manager like [Assets](https://github.com/Stolz/Assets).

Comment: if you're extending `layout.blade.php` why not add all css to that, rather than the `index.blade.php`? also you may want to use [Stacks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#stacks)

Answer (score 0):

`@yield` only use one time from `@section`

So use `@push`
 `@stack` in you main `layout` and many `@push` in multiple views

In your `layout.blade.php` add `@stack('scripts')`

And in `index.blade.php` add

```
@push('scripts')
    <script src="/index.js"></script>
@endpush
```

And in `contact.blade.php` add

```
@push('scripts')
    <script src="/contact.js"></script>
@endpush
```

You can push multiple css or js or content with `@push` and `@stacks`

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#stacks

If you want to disable some css or js in specific page you can make check if page is contact

In `web.php` add route name to `contact page`

Add this to `layout.app.php`

```
@if(request()->route()->getName() != "contact")
  Load your css here as page not contact
@endif
```

So if you open contact page the css not loaded as route name is `contact`

Comment: that's new thing to know but my question is how to remove css or script that comes from ***layout.blade.php***

Comment: Just give your route name and add check before css in layout.blade.php to check if route not the contact page then load css check end of answer